# Is the number a sum of 2 cubes?

Tags: javascript

Im having a bit of bother with my script and im hoping someone could help out, i have a feeling im missing something simple, but another pair of eyes would be great.

Code as follows:

```js
sumOfTwoCubes(91);

function sumOfTwoCubes($number) {
  var cube;
  var limit;
  var i, j, k;
  cube = $number;
  limit = Math.ceil(Math.exp(Math.log(cube) / 3));
  for (i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= limit; j++) {
      k = i * i * i + j * j * j;
      if (k == cube) {
        var out = "True";
      } else {
        var out = "False";
      }
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = out;
}
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: You don't leave the loop when the result has been found. In the next iteration, `out` is changed to `false` again.

Comment: Declare `out` along with the other variables and reinitialise it for each iteration. This will fix your issue

Comment: This program is small enough that you can step through every line in a debugger. Try it with `sumOfTwoCubes(2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```js
function sumOfTwoCubes($number)
{
  var cube;
  var limit;
  var i, j, k;
  cube = $number;
  limit = Math.ceil(Math.exp(Math.log(cube)/3));
  for(i = 1; i <= limit; i++){
    for(j = 1; j <= limit; j++){
      k = i * i * i + j * j * j;
      if(k == cube){
        return document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "TRUE";
      }
    }
  }
  return document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "False";
}

sumOfTwoCubes(91);
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was a nice answer

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is end your loop when you found the correct answer!

```
sumOfTwoCubes(91);
function sumOfTwoCubes($number)
{
  var cube;
  var limit;
  var i, j, k;
  var out = "False";
  cube = $number;
  limit = Math.ceil(Math.exp(Math.log(cube)/3));
    for(i = 1; i <= limit; i++){
      for(j = 1; j <= limit; j++){
        k = i * i * i + j * j * j;
        if(k == cube){
          var out = "True";
          break;
        }
      }
      if (out == "True")
        break;
    }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Now it does show `"True"`!
All I done is:
- Added a break when the `k == cube`, so it will leave the inner `for`.
- Added an `if (out == "True") break;`, so if the `out` is `"True"`, it will end your loop and you will see a `"True"` message inside `result` element!

Comment: @Psi said the same thing in the comments of the question.